# UVA 10324 Zeroes and One

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I was trying a question from UVA ([10324](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=1265)) but always keep on getting Time Limit in the soution. I am pretty sure the code is correct but still the code goes into infinite loop. I have tried this question 6 times but can't seem to pass it.

Can someone shed some light on what could be wrong:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ii=1;
        boolean flag = false;
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            if(str.trim().isEmpty())
                break;
            int TC = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Case " +ii+++":");
            while(TC-->0){
                flag = false;
                int a = sc.nextInt();
                int b = sc.nextInt();
                int c=0;
                if(a>b){
                    c=a;
                    a=b;
                    b=c;
                }
                c = str.charAt(a)-'0';
                for(int i=a+1;i<=b;i++){
                    if(str.charAt(i)-'0' != c){
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(flag?"No":"Yes");
            }
            try{
                sc.nextLine();
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                break;
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: The `-'0'` is unnecessary

Comment: c is the a-indexed integer. `Integer.parseInt()` or -'0' is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the running of the `for(int i=a+1;i<=b;i++)` loop inside the while loop that's inefficient. This has to scan through most of the string each time.

Because there are multiple test cases for each input string, then you can create another data structure that's more efficient to query.

Before the while loop, create an array that stores the number of times the characters have changed since the start of the string, for each position:

```
int total = 0;
int changes[] = new int[str.length()];
for(int i = 1; i < changes.length; i++) {
    if(str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i - 1)) {
        total++;
    }
    changes[i] = total;
}
```

Then the flag can be set as:

```
boolean flag = (changes[a] != changes[b]);
```

Comment: ohhhh. It runs multiple times for a given string. will change that and see it tomorrow. Thanks :)